# Issue with Appium Environment Setup in Mac OS

Tags: appium

Working in latest version of IOS.

Anyone provide steps to run and record the script in latest version appium IOS

Comment: Can go through my blog post [here](http://smritituteja.in/ios-mobile-automation-using-appium/) if it helps!!

Answer (score 1):

To Setup

1. You need to download Appium's latest version from [here](http://appium.io/)
2. Just drag and drop the appium file to Applications folder
3. Start it just with double click from applications

To work with Appium You can watch tutorial videos on YouTube. One is my [own](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-mOG3JuYuJs)